# Getting entity names from context in EF 4

Tags: entity-framework

I'd like to get all my entities' names from context and property names from entity. The second problem can be resolved using reflection but how to do the first part?

For example, I've got entities `User` and `Address`, each user has address. As result I need to get the following:

```
Entity: User
Property: LastName
Property: FirstName
Property: Address

Entity: Address
Property: City
Property: Street
```

Answer (score 0):

To start, the entities (base type `ComplexObject`) are actually distinct from the context, being housed in their own classes.

If you want to find all the entity types, you can use relfection to search the current assembly for any type that inherits `ComplexObject` like so:

```
List<Type> Types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(T => T.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ComplexObject))).ToList();
```

Each of these types is defined with an `EdmxComplexType` attribute, which gives you the namespace name and complex type name. You can get those attributes, for each type `T`, like this:

```
T Instance_Of_T = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(T);
System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EdmxComplexTypeAttribute complexTypeAttr = TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(Instance_Of_T).OfType<System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EdmxComplexTypeAttribute>().ToList().Single();

string NamespaceName = complexTypeAttr.NamespaceName;
string TypeName = complexTypeAttr.Name;
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks. It helps but i had to use keyword 'entity' instead of 'complex' , for example, EdmEntityTypeAttribute